# How to add a external cluster for deployment from ArgoCD CLI

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, argocd, gitops

I have a couple of cluster(Minikube and Kubeadm) setup in my local. I have installed ArgoCD in my Minikube cluster. I am able to perform deployment on the same and it works. Now I need to deploy to the kubeadm cluster setup from ArgoCD installed in Minikube. How can I add or establish a connection between them!

`argocd cluster add CONTEXT` Also how to use this command in CLI?

Answer (score 0):

if you have context locally set of another cluster or not

you can check the existing all content using the

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

and using the same context name you can add the context to the argo CD

`argocd cluster add RESPECTIVE-CONTEXT` name